# Multiple backgrounds on body, using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set multiple backgrounds for the document `body`. Why isn't this code working?

```
body
{
    background: url(../Images/StandardBackgroundPattern.png) repeat, url(../Images/StandardBackground.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

This code only displays the Photo. No pattern to be seen anywhere (but Dev Tools says that both the Photo and pattern have been loaded).

---

<sup>The intended effect of the above is to include a background photo, centered and filling up the width and height of the viewport, and to place a pattern ontop of that and repeat it both horizontally and vertically.</sup>

It would be preferable to avoid using multiple `div`'s for this if possible.

Comment: JSFiddle,net Demo please...with actual images.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this. It should work fine.

```
body {
background-image: url(first.png), url(second.png);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @user I am trying this now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `background` shorthand property. You can use this shorthand method.

```
body{
background: url(first.png) center bottom no-repeat, url(second.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't this code working?

Because that's a syntax error.

> It would be preferable to avoid using multiple div's for this if
>   possible.

Sorry. You'll have to do it in your un-preferable way. Or, split the image itself and then use it.